# "I would like to ask you a favour" vs. "I would like to ask you for a favour"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions, writing-style

Which form is to be preferred?

> - I would like to ask you a favour.
> - I would like to ask you *for* a favour.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to this [Google NGram](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=ask+you+a+favor%2C+ask+you+for+a+favor%2C+ask+you+a+favour%2C+ask+you+for+a+favour&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3), all of the following forms are in use:

- ask you a favo(u)r
- ask you for a favo(u)r

[image: A frequency graph comparing "ask you a favor" (blue), "ask you for a favor" (red), "ask you a favour" (green), and "ask you for a favour" (yellow). Blue and green are consistently much higher than red and yellow; blue starts outpacing green around 1935, and wins completely by 1965. Red and yellow are just about even until 1940, after which red starts outpacing yellow.]

As you can see, the forms without the preposition *for* are more common (with "ask you a favor" generating the highest results). In common use, one may conclude that this is the preferred form.

Comment: Wow, looks like American spelling is creaming British spelling! Gah! I like all those superfluous Us!

Comment: No! It's just that there is a lot more of them!

Answer (score 5):

[BBC Learning English](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/) uses just the former expression for [asking a favour](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/radio/specials/142_requests_offers/page9.shtml).

Answer (score 2):

I would say the former is preferred/more common in colloquial/spoken English. The latter is not incorrect but used less often.

Comment: While i agree it is the more common it is one of my pet peeves.  Is adding one word to make it accurate that hard?

Comment: For some people, it would appear that it *is* ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Compare it with "Asking a lunch" and "Asking for a lunch"
Here, "lunch" is not the actual thing which is being asked; and that's why it should be "Asking for a lunch"

But in case of favour, it's the "favour" which is directly being asked.

Similarly, you can also compare
1. Asking a date
2. Asking for a date

**So the correct usage is**: "I would like to ask you a favour"

Comment: I see your reasoning. Unfortunately, English Isn't required to be logical like that. What people actually say is more relevant, and they actually say "... ask a favour". I think it is just eliding *of you*, so actually makes sense.

Comment: Sorry, but I fail to see kookaburra's point: as I see it, in "asking for a lunch" the lunch is the actual thing being asked, just as it is in "asking for some money", etc. Maybe "ask you a favour" is sort of shorthand for "ask you if you can do me a favour"? I don't know, or maybe, as a very frequent phrase it just got simplified.

Comment: You're saying, I guess, that in the shorter question, the speaker is presuming that the listener knows who is to provide the favor or lunch or whatever.  I think you're right that the shortened version is heard in speach and that its meaning is understood. "Can you do me a favor" has become an American idiom, as has the more direct (and rudely commanding) "do me a favor."  There is a definite difference between the two statements in tone, if nothing else, the first being a bit rude and presumputuous.  Kookaburra asks a good question if you take into consideration issues of tone and etiquette.